# Any Idea How to Implement the Sigma lens with vertex shader

Tags: opengl-3, vertex-shader

I am trying to implement the [Sigma Lens](http://www.lri.fr/~appert/website/papers/SigmaLenses.pdf) in OpenGL using shaders, but having some problems.

I pass the texture coordinates to the vertex shader and i tried to do the spatial transformation for the focus region and the transition region. But this doesnt work, i only get the orginal image.

Here is the code for the vertex shader.

```
in vec4 vVertex;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
//in vec4 vNormal;

uniform mat4   mvpMatrix;
//uniform mat4   mvMatrix;
//uniform mat4   normalMatrix;
uniform float  mm;
uniform float  mouseX;
uniform float  mouseY;

// Texture Coordinate to fragment program
smooth out vec2 vVaryingTexCoord;
smooth out vec2 vVaryingcolorCoord;

void main(void) 
    {
    // Pass on the texture coordinates 
    //vVaryingTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    vec2 m = vec2(mouseX,mouseY);
    vec2 pos = vec2(vTexCoord.s,vTexCoord.t);
    if (distance(pos.xy, m.xy) <=0.1) {
        vVaryingcolorCoord.s = m.x + (pos.x-m.x)/mm;
        vVaryingcolorCoord.t = m.y + (pos.y-m.y)/mm;

    }
    else if(0.1 < distance(pos.xy, m.xy) && distance(pos.xy, m.xy) <= 0.2){
        vVaryingcolorCoord.s = m.x + (pos.x-m.x)/0.8;
        vVaryingcolorCoord.t = m.y + (pos.y-m.y)/0.8;

    }
    else {
     vVaryingcolorCoord.st=vTexCoord.st;

    }

    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;
   }
```

Is there any thing that i am missing, I am just starting to learn Opengl and GLSL, so please any idea is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your MouseX and MouseY values are converted to the right value range? I assume you are drawing a full screen grid of smaller cells here?

Answer (score 0):

This shader makes little sense without the OpenGL code in which it is used. I have a suspicion what's wrong, but I can't tell without the rendering code.